# NetSuite Saved Search where {location} = {user.location}?

Tags: mysql, sql, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

This seems like it should be simple, but for some reason I can't get this to work... I am trying to build a transaction saved search that shows the user (person viewing the search) all transfer orders that have their location in either the {location} field or {transferlocation} field. Here is the formula (Numeric) I am adding to the criteria and setting is equal to 1:

```
CASE WHEN {location} = {user.location} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Seems pretty simple, but this formula errors out. I have also tried this and it doesn't error, but I get 0 results:

```
CASE WHEN {location} LIKE {user.location} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Once I get this to succeed I should be able to either add to this formula or add a new formula criteria for the {transferlocation}. Either way, any suggestions would be great. Below I will add all criteria/results/filters just for transparency:

**Criteria:**

Main Line `is True`

Type `is Transfer Order`

Status `is any of Transfer Order:Partially Fulfilled, Transfer Order:Pending Approval, Transfer Order:Pending Fulfillment, Transfer Order:Pending Receipt, Transfer Order:Pending Receipt/Partially Fulfilled`

*(not working)* Formula (Numeric) `is 1` `CASE WHEN {user.location} = {location} OR {user.location} = {transferlocation} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

**Results:**

Date Created

Document Number

Location

To Location

**Filters:**

Date Created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely due to NetSuite perceiving the possibility of data type differences. Try wrapping your location fields in NVL and/or TO_CHAR or using ...location.id}

Comment: I would give this to both answers if I could, comparing the internal ID worked, this was the formula I ended up going with:

` CASE WHEN {location.id} = {user.location.id} OR {transferlocation.id} = {user.location.id} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `

Answer (score 2):

In a lot of case, when you use Numeric Formula, it seems like NS prefer using internalIds, so use this in your formula and it should work (tested):

```
CASE WHEN {location.id} = {user.location.id} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I would give this to both answers if I could, comparing the internal ID worked, this was the formula I ended up going with: ` CASE WHEN {location.id} = {user.location.id} OR {transferlocation.id} = {user.location.id} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `